# Air temperature drop by water mist cooling

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, evaporation, cooling, humidity

if we have a volume of air (1m3/1'200g) at a certain temp (25°c) and let water evaporate into it, what is the max achievable air temp drop? how much water has evaporated (i guess i can calculate the latter myself, just to check if im correct)? disregarding warming of water, latent heat of evap only. there is more water than neccessary to reach 100% relative humidity.

i asume the calculation is quite complicated, is there a table somewhere to look it up?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the current humidity.  The concept you are looking for is called the [wet-bulb temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet-bulb_temperature):

> The wet-bulb temperature is defined as the temperature of a parcel of air cooled to saturation (100% relative humidity) by the evaporation of water into it, with the latent heat supplied by the parcel.[2](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/wet-bulb) A wet-bulb thermometer indicates a temperature close to the true (thermodynamic) wet-bulb temperature. The wet-bulb temperature is the lowest temperature that can be reached under current ambient conditions by the evaporation of water only.

There are many [calculators](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/wet-bulb) out there which can do the calculation you seek.  That particular link offers the equation they use:

$$
\begin{align}
T_w = & T * \arctan[0.151977 * (r_h + 8.313659)^\frac 1 2] \\ + & \arctan(T + r_h) \\
- &\arctan(r_h - 1.676331) \\
+ & 0.00391838 *(r_h)^\frac 3 2 \cdot \arctan(0.023101 \cdot r_h) \\- &4.686035
\end{align}
$$

Where $T_w$ is the wet bulb temperature in Celsius, $T$ is the temperature of the air in Celsius, and $r_h$ is the relative humidity expressed on a percentage scale from 0-100.